# EJB persistence issue with OSGI

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, ejb-3.0, osgi

I am beginning to use EJB for a project (the [eCOM Project](http://ecom.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) actually).

I have some beans that I need to save to a database, like a Status bean.
The code that does this is :

```
Status status = new Status();
statut.setLabel("the_label");
this.em.persist(status);
```

This is the stacktrace I get when trying to save an object to database :

```
22 avr. 2011 19:09:42 com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator handleFullLogging
ATTENTION: IOP00810064: Unable to load proxy class for interfaces 
    [javax.validation.constraints.NotNull] because codebase URL 
    osgi://org.glassfish.hk2.external.bean-validator/1.1.0 is malformed
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ATTENTION: IOP00810064: Unable to load proxy class for interfaces 
    [javax.validation.constraints.NotNull] because codebase URL 
    osgi://org.glassfish.hk2.external.bean-validator/1.1.0 is malformed  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 64  completed: No
...
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: osgi
```

Do you have any explanation on what could have gone wrong here ?

Comment: It looks like somebody hasn't registered a URL protocol handler for the "osgi" protocol. I believe this is a Glassfish-specific issue and you would have better luck tagging it with the "glassfish" tag.

Answer (score 0):

JSR-303 validations and remoting does not match together well. See [GLASSFISH-17003](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17003).